# What kind of parameters should receive a function which use data provider of Object[][] type in Test NG?

Tags: java, testng

I'm trying to implement test which will use several data providers. First of all I've created a data provider class

```
public class FreightAuthenticatedDataProvider {

    @DataProvider(name = "correctUsercorrectFreight")
    public static Object[][] correctUsercorrectFreight() {
        return new Object[][] {
                               {UserDataProvider.correctUsers(),
                                FreightDataProvider.correctFreights()}
         }; 
     }
}
```

In this class, **UserDataProvider.correctUsers()** and **FreightDataProvider.correctFreights()** are collections iterators. On this step, every collection is properly initialized. 
Then I refer to my data provider from test method:

```
@Test(dataProviderClass = FreightAuthenticatedDataProvider.class, dataProvider = "correctUsercorrectFreight")
public void createSimpleFreight(User user, Freight freight) {
    // test actions
}
```

And the following error occurs in my test method **The data provider is trying to pass 1 parameters but the method ...#createSimpleFreight takes 2 and TestNG is unable in inject a suitable object**

Can you tell me, what type of parameter is supposed to be passed in the test method? Also if you know a better solution, please comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your dataprovider. You are creating just one parameter per test. Parameters for one call go into the same "line" of the 2D array.

Try this:

```
public class FreightAuthenticatedDataProvider {

    @DataProvider(name = "correctUsercorrectFreight")
    public static Object[][] correctUsercorrectFreight() {
        return new Object[][] {
              // when correctUser() and correctFreights() return Lists, 
              // than it needs to be converted, see comments
              {UserDataProvider.correctUsers(), FreightDataProvider.correctFreights()}
         }; 
     }
}
```

Comment: Okay. I've fixed FreightAuthenticatedDataProvider class. Now there is the "argument type mismatch" error. What I am supposed to do to extract this data in the test method in the proper way?

Comment: Oh I guess correctUsers() and correctFreights() give back Lists. You need to convert the lists to User-Freight pairs. Simply think "one row = one method call". its like {{user1, freight1},{user2, freight2}, ...}